# Resource blocked by CORS policy in Serverless API Gateway Lambda even though its set up

Tags: aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, aws-lambda-edge

I am using Serverless and I have a lambda that is available via API Gateway. Like many of the CORs questions that mention a similar stack, I am getting the following error when making a call from a browser (usual Postman/curl local testing works just fine):

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://<gatewayUrl>/dev/login/?userType=userA' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field z-client-timezone is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response
```

- The Integration Request type is `Lambda_Proxy`
- Cors has been enabled, adding the Options Method
- The lambda handler returns the expected headers
- The axios request sends one custom header `Z-Client-Timezone` that is also allowed in the Lambda
- I've tried everything including everything [here](https://www.serverless.com/blog/cors-api-gateway-survival-guide), but no luck.

I'm extremely frustrated so any help would be awesome. One more thing, when I do `curl -i -X OPTIONS https://<gatewayUrl>/dev/login` I get this result, which seems to be missing `Z-Client-Timezone`:

```
HTTP/2 200
content-type: application/json
content-length: 0
date: Fri, 10 Jul 2020 04:00:10 GMT
x-amzn-requestid: <aws_requestId>
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token
x-amz-apigw-id: <apigw-id>
access-control-allow-methods: OPTIONS,POST
via: 1.1 <id>.cloudfront.net (CloudFront), 1.1 <id>.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-pop: DFW50-C1
x-cache: Miss from cloudfront
x-amz-cf-pop: DFW55-C1
x-amz-cf-id: <cf-id>
```

**My Lambda:**

```
export async function login(event) {

    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
    }

    ....
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(session)
    };
}
```

**My Serverless.yml:**

```
login:
  handler: dist/src/handlers/auth.login
  events:
    - http:
        path: login
        method: post
        cors: 
          origin: '*'
          headers:
           - Access-Control-Allow-Credentials

resources:
  Resources:
    GatewayResponseDefault4XX:
        Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::GatewayResponse'
        Properties:
            ResponseParameters:
              gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
              gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'*'"
            ResponseType: DEFAULT_4XX
            RestApiId:
              Ref: 'ApiGatewayRestApi'
```

I would love any help you can give. I've omitted some code as everything else works except for the cors stuff so I've just included that but if more clarification is needed, I'm happy to provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your lambda function is allowing the Z-Client-Timezone header, the built-in options method of AWS is not.

In order to allow this, you can do the following -

```
login:
  handler: dist/src/handlers/auth.login
  events:
    - http:
        path: login
        method: post
        cors: 
          origin: '*'
          headers:
           - Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
           - Z-Client-Timezone
```

Then add any other headers you are also sending.